# css - update div margin/position based on content height

Tags: css

I am creating a page layout. The page content (in the example shown as text dynamic content) changes height but always has the same width.

I would like to calculate the top margin of my content (or position the content accordingly) using the following formula:
`100vh - dynamic content height * 0.4`

Is there a way to achieve this using css rules, or do I need to know the height of my dynamic content in advance?

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.content {
  width: 320px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>
    Some dynamic content...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you can't know the height of the dynamic content before it rendered on tha page. So you have to use js to do this.

Comment: Agreed with @Miha. When there is dynamic content JS need's to be implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform: translateY(calc(100vh - 40%))` since [translateY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY#Values) percentage relates to the element's height:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.content {
  width: 320px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(calc(50vh - 40%)); /** I've used 50vh to avoid scrolling **/
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>
    Some dynamic content...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič or like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m1np3o08/1/ and you will have better support since calc() inside translate is buggy in some browser.